# Styling Leaflet Maps

Tags: leaflet

Is there anyway to style base maps using Leaflet?  I know there are quite a few options for loading different pre-made styles (such as Stamen, Mapbox, etc...), but I am looking for a way to create my own style without going back to Google Map's API.  Or is there a way to style one of the particular base maps?

Basically, I'd like to keep using Leaflet for this project as it is quite nice and simple, but without that ability I'll have to move on.  Thanks.

Edit:  Is there a way, through Leaflet, to use Google Maps custom styling?  I like the coding aspects of Leaflet as compared to GMaps, but still would like the flexibility in terms of design that custom styling of the tiles gives me.  As this is a very small project, I don't want to set up my own Tile Map Server if possible.

Comment: I think you need to describe what you mean by the base map, and why you think its a leaflet issue. Leaflet (typically) just shows map tiles from a Tile Map Server (TMS). How they get generated / styled is nothing to do with Leaflet. Perhaps go up a level and describe *why* you think you need to do something different, and the higher context (e.g. map data source).

Comment: By the way, Mapbox does let you customize their base map.

Comment: Openlayers works with styled google maps. So are you sure that with leaflet you can't show customized google map layers?

Comment: Not sure at all.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Josh You can.  Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/crofty/2197701) of using Google Map's Tile Service.  But always check [TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/usage) to make sure you don't have an outage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think google maps custom styles are going to work anywhere except google maps...

Perhaps you could consider [Cloudmade's styling](http://maps.cloudmade.com/editor) or [Mapbox styling](http://mapbox.com/blog/custom-styles-mapbox-streets/)  as suggested by Scro.

Comment: I would second this and add that the cloudmade style editor is very very good!

Comment: Cloudmade was the way to go.  As Cloudmade and Leaflet are made by the same company, their integration is pretty good.  But they left off Cloudmade as a potential in their list of "other" providers so I didn't catch it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Google map custom styles do work in leaflet. I would also suggest [tangram](https://mapzen.com/projects/tangram/) by mapzen. It's similar to mapbox custom styling.